# How can I send an email from Apache superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I'm facing Authentication unsuccessful error when I try to send mail from Apache Superset.

I checked the document's SMTP integration chapter:https://apache-superset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

I changed SMTP_PASSWORD parameter and I entered password manually in my config.py file like SMTP_PASSWORD = "'xxx!!'" (I added '' because my password includes special character like '!'. Also, I tried SMTP_PASSWORD="xx!!" but also I'm getting error.

smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful')

I can login with my SMTP user via browser (Exchange). Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Apache Superset version:  1.3.2
Python version:3.8
OS version: RHEL 8

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to poke at this by checking your SMTP connection from inside your Superset instance.

From where your Superset instance should be sending the emails, start a Python script and try:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpservername.yourdomain', yourportnumber)
```

If that command fails or hangs indefinitely, you know there's a connection problem.  You might try connecting to the GMail SMTP server or another known-to-work set of credentials and seeing if that works to narrow it down.

For instance, if running Superset with `docker-compose` you would enter the worker container with `docker exec -it superset_worker /bin/bash`, run `python`, and try this there.

My scheduled reports were failing and doing this helped me isolate a cause: my Superset instance could not connect to the target unauthenticated SMTP server.